# Add font-awesome icon to one option in select created by an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, font-awesome, angularjs-ng-if

Is it possible to add an icon to an option in a dropdown based on if it matches a certain setting from the data returned in an ng-repeat?

I have the following select and the options within that select are created via an ng-repeat that is going off of the data records pulled back from the database.

```
<select id="playListOpt" class="form-control"
        ng-model="playlistItem.selectedObjectId"
        ng-change="resetModal()" ng-required="true">
    <option role="option" value="0" selected>
      @Resources.L_LMS_ActDetails.CreateNewPlaylist
    </option>
    <option role="option" ng-repeat="playlistItem in playlistDataForActivity"
            value="{{playlistItem.Id}}">                                        
      {{playlistItem.Name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

As it loops over the playlistDataForActivity is it possible to find the item that has IsDefault = 1 and add an icon next to that option?

This works by changing the color of the option that is set to 'Default' by using the ng-style attribute. **What's the best way to add a FontAwesome icon?**

```
<select id="playListOpt" class="form-control"
        ng-model="playlistItem.selectedObjectId" ng-change="resetModal()"
        ng-required="true">
    <option role="option" value="0">
      @Resources.L_LMS_ActDetails.CreateNewPlaylist
    </option>
    <option role="option" ng-repeat="playlistItem in playlistDataForActivity" 
            ng-style="playlistItem.IsDefault && {'color' : 'red'}"
            value="{{playlistItem.Id}}">
      {{playlistItem.Name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Mind the tags, this is a question about angularjs, not `angular`.

Comment: An option can only contain text: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: @JBNizet  Since font-awesome icons are fonts, they can be added to options by Unicode. See [Add font-awesome icon to option in select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55977212/5535245).

Comment: @georgeawg Ah yes indeed. I'm using the the SVG icons now, so I guess that's a drawback of using SVG.

Comment: Any idea how to add that within an Ng-repeat on the particular option that is set to IsDefault? Thanks!