# Add font-awesome icon to option in select

Tags: angularjs, font-awesome, angularjs-select

Is it possible to add font-awesome icon to`<option>` in `<select>`?

```
  <body ng-app>
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> fa-camera-retro<br>
    <select ng-model="choice" class="fa">
      <option value="">Choose</option>
      <option value="icon camera">icon camera</option>
      <option value="icon bell">icon bell</option>
      <option value="icon bicycle">icon bicycle</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since font-awesome icons are fonts, they can be added to options by Unicode:

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
  <body ng-app>
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> fa-camera-retro<br>
    <select ng-model="choice" class="fa">
      <option value="">Choose</option>
      <option value="&#xf030; camera">&#xf030; camera</option>
      <option value="&#xf0f3; bell">&#xf0f3; bell</option>
      <option value="&#xf206; bicycle">&#xf206; bicycle</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Choice = <span class="fa">{{choice}}</span>
    <br><span class="fa">&#xf030;-&#xf0f3;-&#xf206;</span>
  </body>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/D8i7qmodUhziumKs0IWX?p=preview)

The [Font-Awesome Cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/)